# Blockchain is losing me money with every transfer

Tags: blockchain

I'm losing up to 45% on a BTC transaction. When it reaches the merchant they say that I'm losing it in the transfer and that the chain is the cause. How true is this and how can I check with the chain on what's going on?

Comment: 45% of what? the btc sent? this does not sound correct, watch out for scamming merchants, as soon as u have sent your btc there is no getting it sent back without the merchant sending back to you etc

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking up your transaction on a blockchain explorer like https://www.blockchain.com/explorer ? How much did you pay in mining fees as a proportion of the entire transaction amount?